# Can I install Windows on M.2 SSD in HP 15-bs564ur so built-in HDD provides extra storage?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, m.2

Can I install Windows on an M.2 SSD in an HP 15-bs564ur,  and have its built in HDD serve as extra storage? This laptop provides an M.2 slot but I'm not sure which form-factor (like 2280, etc.). Is there some kind of a manual for that?

Answer (score 1):

The [repair manual for this model](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05493257) says the M.2 slot will work if you do not have a Pentium or Celeron CPU and illustrates how to install it on pp. 56-58. Since that model has a Core CPU [according to the spec sheet](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-bs000-laptop-pc/15551412/model/17572113/document/c05623401), it will work. It's a 2280.

Comment: Frustrating that the spec sheet did not mention the M.2 slot, apologies for earlier incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to deactivate you're internal HDD controller (presumably SATA) in order to use the M.2 SSD it should be possible. However, booting from the M.2 SSD has to be supported by the BIOS in order to install windows on it. This should be explained in you're laptop's manual.